# How to calculate disabled items above the current index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to add background red on only immediate diabled li above Current Index.
Is there any way to calculate it?
Right now it is apply to all the disabled li. But I just want immediate one.

Thanks in Adnvace :)

```js
$( "li.component" ).prevAll(".component.disabled").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="component disabled">Disabled</li>
    <li class="component">Index</li>
    <li class="component disabled">Disabled</li>
    <li class="component disabled">Disabled</li>
    <li class="component">Current Index</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:contains('Current Index')` to select the element with that text:

```js
$( "li.component:contains('Current Index')").prev().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="component disabled">Disabled</li>
    <li class="component">Index</li>
    <li class="component disabled">Disabled</li>
    <li class="component disabled">Disabled</li>
    <li class="component">Current Index</li>
    </ul>
```

If you only want to select the previous list element if it contains the disabled class, then change the selector to `$( "li.component:contains('Current Index')").prev('li.disabled').css( "background-color", "red" );`

If you need to find the first list item with the disabled class starting with the element with the text Current Index, then use `$( "li.component:contains('Current Index')").prevUntil('li.disabled').prev().css( "background-color", "red" );`

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/